Proof regarding the set of all subsets of natural numbers
I cannot find the fault in this proof which seems to prove that there does exist a bijection from the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ to the set of $\mathbb N$.
For some subset, say $K$, we define $f(K)$ to be the product of all
$p_{i} \forall i \in K$.
Ex: for the subset $\{1,2,4\}$, its function would be equal to $3 \times 5 \times 11 = 165$. (I have taken 2 to be the 0th prime)
This is clearly injective as for the functions of two different sets to be equal each of their prime factors must be same and thus they should have exactly the same element.
From the topics covered in class, there is always an surjection from any infinite set to the natural numbers.
Can we not conclude from Schröder-Bernstein that there must exist a bijection. Have I misunderstood the statement of Schröder-Bernstein or is there some fallacy I am overlooking?

What is $f(\mathbb{N})$?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You've stumbled onto something interesting.

I found the mistake in my proof. The other answers(at the time of me writing this) don't seem to address this error in particular. However, one of the comments on my question did. The problem is that the product of infinite natural numbers does not lie within the set of natural numbers itself, it instead is a super natural number.

Your function is not well defined because the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ contains infinite sets. However, this is what the proof that the set of all finite sets of natural number has same cardinality as the natural numbers looks like.

Your $f(K)$ injects the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb N$ itself.  Mapping a natural number to the singleton subset containing it gives another injection in the opposite direction.  So the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable by Schröder–Bernstein.  (The "bit-string" mapping sending $K$ to $\sum_{k \in K} 2^{k-1}$ gives an explicit bijection.)
There is no injection of all subsets of $\Bbb N$, the power set $2^{\Bbb N}$, into $\Bbb N$ itself by Cantor's theorem.
